# Bypass the SED SSD drive password request

Tags: ssd, bios

I have a Lenovo z50-70 with new Crucial MX300 SSD drive. The drive supports SED. I just set password for the SED using Live Linux USB however password was probably too long and when I turn the computer on, it asks for password but does not allow me to enter the whole password. Moreover I cannot even get into BIOS, or boot the Live Linux, without entering the password. When I unplug the SSD I can boot the Live Linux without any problem. Is there a way to boot from the USB into the Live Linux without entering the SSD password? Will then be possible to change the password with hdparm?

One of the options I was thinking about was booting into Live Linux withiut the SSD connected and then plugging the SSD in. Do you think this is safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved it by using SATA to USB adapter. Took the drive out, booted into Live Linux, connected the SSD with the adapter. It was possoible to disable the security with password that I set before.